# How do i copy data ,if i assigned one number to each row in one column,map this column data with another column using number in 3rd column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Depending on Mapping number column data of Name2 should map to Name column.

I am not getting any idea how to achieve this in vba …… plz help me….

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're after

```
Dim findMappingNo As Range
Dim mapNum As Integer

For i = 2 to 11

   Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:= Range("H" & i)

   mapNum = Range("D" & i).Value
   Set findMappingNo = Range("B2:B11").Find(what:=mapNum)

   If Not findMappingNo Is Nothing Then
      Range("C" & findMappingNo.Row).Copy Destination:= Range("I" & i)
   End if

Next i
```

If you want the result list to be on another sheet, just place the sheet name at the start of the ranges, ie,

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:= Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & i)
```